# Glass prism - refractive index

Tags: mathematical-physics

> Light falls perpendicular on one side of a glass prism with refractive index  **n**. The light is totally reflected on the right side.
>
> 1.1: Determine the angle of incidence using the figure below.
>
> 1.2: What's the smallest value **n** can have?
>
> 1.3: When the prism is immersed into a liquid with refractive index **1.15** there is still total internal reflection. But when it's immersed into water with refractive index **1.33** then the total internal reflection disappears. Give the boundaries of the possible values for **n**.
>
> [image]

I'm new to optics and found this one in some textbook I found in the library.

Here were my ideas:

1.1: Wouldn't the angle of incidence would just be $45°$ then?

1.2: I looked up some formulas on wiki and found this one:

$n_1\sin{\alpha_1}=n_2\sin{\alpha_2}$, meaning I would need to plugin $45°$ into $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$, but that doesn't get me in anywhere.

1.3: I have no idea how to approach this one.

Can anyone more knowledgeable in optics help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as this is not homework:

1.1: Yes.

1.2: If you are taking a class, then you had better learn this equation well, as it is Snell's Law, or the law of refraction.  $\alpha_1$ is indeed the angle of incidence from the surface normal.  $\alpha_2$ is the angle of refraction from the surface normal.  In this case, $\alpha_1 = 45^{\circ}$.  You find $\alpha_2$ given $n_1$ and $n_2$:

$$\sin{\alpha_2} = \frac{n_1}{n_2} \sin{\alpha_1} $$

Note that, if $n_1 \le n_2$, then there will always be light refracted, no matter what the angle of incidence is.  However, if $n_1 \gt n_2$, then there will be some **critical angle** $\alpha_c$ at which $\sin{\alpha_2} =1$, beyond which the light does not refract into the surrounding medium but instead reflects back.

In the case pictured, the light reflects back at an incidence of $\alpha_1=45^{\circ}$, $n_2=1$.  Thus, the smallest value $n_1$ can have is whatever makes $\sin{\alpha_2}=1$, or $n_1 = 1/\sin{\alpha_1} = \sqrt{2} \approx 1.414$.

1.3: You can get the minimum value of $n_1$ the same way I did in 1.2 above for the fluid at $n_2=1.15$.  The maximum value of $n_1$ results using the same condition at $n_2=1.33$.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. About 1.3:I used $\frac{n_2}{\sin{\alpha_1}}$ and got $n_1\approx 1.6264$ for $n_2=1.15$ and $n_1\approx 1.88$ for $n_2=1.33$. Is that correct?

Comment: @RafaFafa: yup.